# Why say "student life" and not "the student life"?

Tags: definite-article, phrase-choice, indefinite-article, countability, abstract-nouns

The Culture subsection of the [*Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/)'s entry for ["campus"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/campus) begins with

> The popular image of **student life** is of young people with few responsibilities enjoying themselves and doing very little work. This is often not true.

Why didn't it say "the student life" or "a student life"?

Comment: So if I say "a student life" I would be talking about one student, but "student life" means students lifestyle?

Comment: That's great thank you John, you have answered many of my question :-)

Comment: You're welcome Sara; you may find [this page](http://www.writing.utoronto.ca/advice/english-as-a-second-language/articles) helpful as it has a lot of useful advice about when and when not to use articles.

Comment: To further complicate things: [think student life](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22think+student+life%22) gets dozens of hits in Google Books without the article, and none at all *with* it. [But the student **lifestyle**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22but+the+student+lifestyle%22) gets several hits ***with*** the article, and none at all *without* it. No amount of grammar rules will "explain" why ***life*** and ***lifestyle*** are "different" - it's just established idiomatic preference. Some things you just gotta learn by rote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting point. I think it may be because "life" is more of a concept in that context, and a "lifestyle" is a defined thing.

Comment: @snailboat Would you mind pointing out what the errors were?

Comment: @Catija Okay, done. Posted as an answer and deleted my related comments.

Comment: Added more context to the question since it made no sense that an OED entry began like that. Apparently, they've added a "culture" section to some learner's entries to both raise and correct common misconceptions as well as to align readers more with Oxford's own interests. ("In Britain reduced government support for higher education...")

Answer (score 1):

> The popular image of student life ...

The noun *life* does not refer to a specific instance of *life*, but rather life in general.

Keep in mind that *life* here is actually part of a prepositional phrase which combined serves to qualify *image*.  The sentence talks about an instance of an *image* and therefore that has an article.

Comment: I think you understand this and just misstated for the sake of brevity, but the noun life *is* referring to a specific instance of life: the life of students, thanks to the attributive noun student. It's simply still reckoned as an uncountable concept, rather than taken as a specific example life.

Comment: On the other hand, I don't know why you felt the need to drag the preposition or image into the conversation. That's well off topic, given the OP's very specific concerns and confusions.

Comment: If there isn't a specific student, there can't be a specific student life.

Answer (score 0):

In this case "student" is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) modifying "life" to elaborate on what kind of life is being talked about. Without it, it becomes

> The popular image of life is of...

which means something different but sounds fine. It wouldn't sound right if you added articles, because then without the noun adjunct you'd either be saying

> The popular image of the life is of...

or

> The popular image of a life is of...

which both sound off because you're talking about life in general. You don't mean an individual person's life, so articles aren't used.

Comment: I started to edit this to fix the very buried lede but then realized there were enough omissions that a separate answer is really called for.  I am curious why you go with "noun adjunct" instead of "attributive noun". Just to focus on its irrelevance in the flow of the sentence's structure? It seems like how to best integrate the "student" is OP's actual problem.

Comment: Also, it's not nearly as wrong to add the articles once "life" is being modified in this way: a sailor's life, a peasant's life, a pirate's life, a boy's life, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some grammatical considerations here that you already understand.

The word "[life](https://oed.com/view/Entry/108093)" can be uncountable or countable depending on whether general concepts ("the meaning of life") or a specific example ("This is the life!") is meant. That distinction holds for most of the word's different senses, including those for "a course, condition, or manner of living" that cover how students live their lives.

Separately, both "[a](https://oed.com/view/Entry/4)" and "[the](https://oed.com/view/Entry/200211)" can be used to refer to classes of things. Without other context, saying "A student enjoys [themself](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/someone-who-likes-to-enjoy-themself), having little work and few responsibilities" and "The student enjoys [themself](https://oed.com/view/Entry/334443), having little work and few responsibilities" convey the same 'information' about the referent, some generic student. The emphasis is a little different and (for the reasons discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/290726/is-it-the-or-a-in-the-life-of-peasant)) make the second one sound obnoxious to most people raised in the Anglosphere.

As [Mr Clifford's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/84400/52137) discussed, **it may be that you're still uncomfortable with [adjectival use of nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/noun_adjunct)**. The word "student" in your sentence is not talking about a particular student or even a generic one; it is simply limiting the noun "life" to discuss specifically the manner of living shared by students. It's grammatically correct. Taken as the general concept of "student life", it remains uncountable and no article is needed.

Your confusion about needing articles may come from either of two concerns.

If Mr Clifford was right that you misunderstood [attributive nouns](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attributive), it may be that you wanted the word "student" to be acting as a noun talking about particular people instead of as an adjective limiting the kind of life under discussion. In that case, neither of your suggestions would work. You can talk about the life of a representative student or the life of the generic student, but **you need to use the possessive form to keep "student" as a separate noun**: "the popular image of a student's life is..." or "the popular image of the student's life is..."

**However, it may also be that you're a bit uncomfortable with countability**. If you think that using "student" to modify "life" makes it a special kind of life that might require an article, that's a separate issue. The first thing to realize is that, if "student" is just an adjective modifying "life", any article that you add in front of it will be too. The second thing to realize is that because the countable meanings of "life" are marked by the presence of articles, it becomes ambiguous and awkward if you try to use "a" to discuss classes of the uncountable meanings instead.

In other words,

> Student life isn't all [wine and roses](http://blupete.com/Literature/Poetry/DowsonNotLong.htm).

and

> The student life is not all [beer and skittles](https://wordhistories.net/2018/07/31/beer-skittles-origin/).
>
> A student's life ...
>
> The student's life ...

are largely equivalent. The first is more comfortable, feels shared, and better suits the plural continuation of your sentence. The second isn't wrong but feels more as if a contrast is being drawn with some other mode of life and (as discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/290726/is-it-the-or-a-in-the-life-of-peasant)) makes the speaker seem more judgmental, possibly even obnoxious. All three would be better served by rephrasing the following idea of your sentence singularly or impersonally.

> A student life is ...

a bit off. Even more than "the student life", it should have a singular continuation of your sentence. It also really needs to used in a particular context contrasting it with other modes of life to feel appropriate and get away from referring to the other countable ideas (the nondead status of a student, the life force of a student, the biography of a student, &c). You still see it in the wild—"[A Sailor's Life](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szrGtFxtWXU)", "[A Pirate's Life for Me!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9ZCWMFmQsE)", "A student life is a golden life"—but [it's much, much less common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+student+life%2Ca+student+life&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).